# what are the errors in my def function code structure

Tags: python, function, sum

This program is to write def function for sum of integers given.

```
def find_sum_numbers(sample_list):
    sum_numbers=0
    for x in sample_list:
        sum_numbers=sum_numbers+x
    #return sum_numbers
    print("The sum of the numbers is: ", sum_numbers)
```

The main program:

```
n=input("Please enter a number: ")
sample_list=range(1,n+1))
find_sum_numbers(sample_list)
```

---

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/edX-courses/Python/programs/def sum of numbers.py", line 14, in <module>
    sample_list=range(1,n+1) TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use input it automatically accepts the input as a string, even if a number is entered. What you should do is check if the input is a valid digit and then convert it to an integer.

```
n=input("Please enter a number: ")
if n.isdigit():
    sample_list=range(1,int(n)+1)
else:
    print("You must enter a number")
find_sum_numbers(sample_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the `input` function returns a string and not an integer so you need to convert it before

```
sample_list=range(1, int(n) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

..

```
n=int(input("Please enter a number: "))
sample_list=range(1,n+1))
find_sum_numbers(sample_list)
```

If you are using `python2.7` it by default consider all the input value as `string` datatype. So you need to explicitly convert `string` -> `int`